# TabBar beginCustomizingItems and endCustomizingAnimated in iphone

Tags: iphone, methods, tabbar

Hai.

How and when we use the UITabbar beginCustomizingItems and endCustomizingAnimated methods, can any one guide me about these methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Call beginCustomizingItems when you want to allow the user to edit the order of tab-bar items etc. See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBar/beginCustomizingItems: for details.